# What happened to NormalHuman?

Tags: discussion, specific-user

I've noticed that NormalHuman's automatic tagging/commenting has ceased, and I can't find a trace of his account (user147263)?

I've been less active on M.SE, so can anyone update me on what happened here? Is NormalHuman still active on another account?

Their GitHub account also appears to have [coincidentally ceased activity](https://github.com/normalhuman).

Comment: This was noticed as early as [July 31, 2016](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31392367#31392367).

Comment: People have the right to quit SE if they want. It's not a prison. No reason has to be provided. Discussing publicly like this some user's reasons for quitting SE is not a good use of meta IMO, it's just as bad as when prominent users make threads all about themselves. Maybe they were tired of SE, maybe they wanted a new account not associated to the old one, maybe they quit math, maybe they had a baby and not as much time to contribute, maybe they are an astronaut and just set off to space, who knows? And more to the point, how is it any of your business?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi you're making a number of false inferences. For a start, I didn't even know whether NormalHuman quit MSE or was banned. Saying that NH voluntarily quit MSE would have been entirely sufficient. Note that my question **in no way asks for NH's reasons for quitting**, or any associated gossip. Your aggressive tone is entirely inappropriate.

Comment: Nobody even knows if quitting was voluntary or not beyond staff/mods and the user themselves. And mods typically don't discuss private information with other users. *Your* post is what's inappropriate. Let me ask again: how is it any of your business whether NH quit voluntarily or was forcibly made to quit?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I'm not sure if that's entirely true. High-profile bans and suspensions (Bill Dubuque, amWhy) have historically been quite public knowledge.

Comment: 1/ Suspensions and account deletions aren't the same thing. A user can't suspend their account themselves, so there wouldn't even be a point in asking whether it's voluntary. 2/ You'll notice that all mentions of Bill Dubuque's name were redacted in the post discussing his suspensions, and that in amWhy's case there were many users suspended at once and mods only started commenting after people raised a stink and other people basically told everyone what had happened through deduction.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi regarding "how is it any of your business": this user had an *outsized* impact on MSE. NH's vote patterns led to the deletion of thousands of questions; he participated extensively on MSE Meta and curated statistics, etc. Is it really poor form to ask about the disappearance of an extremely high-profile user? I don't think so.

Comment: The account was right before deletion in a state in which it is when a user induces self-deletion, thus it is overwhelmingly likely that they simply asked for their account to be deleted.

Comment: It seems that the tagging comment stop way before the deletion of the account, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: This time, I strongly disagree with you. I find Newb's question well posed, and I have asked myself the same question. You see, the SE communities are not just places where people gather to have a rational exchange of ideas. They are also places where invisible bonds form among the well-established users, and these bonds are emotionally charged. If suddenly a user disappears, it is... "NormalHuman" to worry about him and to ask the others for news about him. This is what the word "community" implies. This is the difference between a community and a waiting room in an airport.

Comment: @AlexM. this type of concern is more compatible with an account going stale rather than it being deleted (and earlier associated ones on other sites being still around and active). That said I do not see a particular problem with the question either although it could degrade.

Comment: @AlexM. "I have asked myself the same question" This might be precisely Najib's point: you asked yourself (as many users did, I am sure) but you did not post here to ask publicly. Dunno...

Comment: NormalHuman engaged in some highly unusual behaviors that, while some people appreciated, others found very annoying. I think this is a reasonable question if, for no other reason, because it provides an opportunity to reflect on those behaviors. Furthermore, the Normal Account was always anonymous, as far as I know. There's no real world harm here. I would point out also, that the user still has many other Stack accounts.

Comment: @MarkMcClure  your comment is exactly what I mean with degrade.  "There's no real world harm here." What is that supposed to mean exactly? What "real world harm" could there be that cannot happen in this case? Anyway, the activities were discussed a plenty while they were ongoing.

Comment: @MarkMcClure It was not always anonymous e.g. at times he linked to his website https://calculus7.org/ and he also listed in his profile some of his many prior accounts, some of which were abbreviations of his name iirc. He has often abandoned prior accounts and started fresh with new accounts, so I wouldn't be surprised if this is simply the start of another cycle.

Comment: @Newb Now that you got the answer you were allegedly asking for (i.e. "the deletion was voluntary"), can you tell me what you got out of it? How did this help you, what did this tell you?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: While I cannot answer for the OP, what I have found out from comments and **quid**'s answer is that NormalHuman is still active on other SE sites, and on his own site "Calculus VII". This is reassuring, because it means that he hasn't gone through any personal catastrophy (terminal cancer, death in a car accident etc.) - knowing this is relieving and I feel that my day is better. It wouldn't hurt if we were more sympathetic to and care a bit more about each other, in general.

Comment: This question got closed once, then reopened, and it seems that it is going to get closed again. If so, I shall vote for reopening, again. What is this, friends, a wrestling contest? Do you feel that chaos in the world has decreased and order has been restored by you closing this? Hm...

Comment: :( I just noticed this myself (I'm rarely on StackExchange anymore, but I almost immediately noticed his absence in a couple chatrooms).  He's going to be missed.  He's still active on his blog, etc., though, so it's possible that he may return in the future...

Comment: @apnorton: In all honesty I won’t miss him at all. Judging by my limited presence here, he provided many excellent answers here on Meta, and the few answers of his on the main site that I happened to see were good, but in my view his deletion campaign was toxic nonsense verging on outright vandalism. (I am none the less glad to hear that nothing terrible has happened to him.)

Comment: @AlexM. When someone deletes their account on SE, your first thought is that something horrible happened to them? Because of course, when you get hit by a bus or you learn you have cancer, your first item of business is to delete your SE account... And of course, you developed such a strong emotional bond with an anonymous user that you're relieved to hear nothing happened to them when nothing even indicated that. Please, spare me the fakery. Perhaps it's a cultural issue, I believe in some places it's expected of you to start tearing up and say how sorry you are when you hear of any tragedy.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I would certainly have been a little sad if I had learned that something horrible had happened to NH, but I can't say I knew them well enough (or anyone on this website for that matter) to have the level of emotional reaction I see in this thread... My first thoughts when I saw that their account was deleted certainly weren't that a tragedy had happened. A long, sudden inactivity, perhaps (and even then...), but an account deletion? Please!

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: When I first noticed NH's absence (sometime during summer), I wasn't aware that he had deleted his account: for me, he had suddenly just become absent, that was it. It is only due to this question that I found out, several months later, that it was an account deletion. This is the correct chronological order of the events as I have witnessed them. I am also glad that you manage to have such a rational view on the world; now I understand better the concept of "French rationalism". Plus, your brilliant irony! Voltaire would have been proud of you!

Comment: @AlexM [*In epistemology, rationalism is the view that "regards reason as the chief source and test of knowledge" or "any view appealing to reason as a source of knowledge or justification". More formally, rationalism is defined as a methodology or a theory "in which the criterion of the truth is not sensory but intellectual and deductive".*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalism) Care to share how is is in any way relevant to the discussion? Or did you just look at my nationality in my profile, strung up two words that you had already heard together, and tried to make a jab out of it?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott possibly unintentionally your comment misrepresents the mathematical contributions of this user on the main site. They had a considerably higher number of answers on main than on meta. When they deleted their account  they had about 50k points. Moreover, their answers where rather focused on more specialized questions that had not gotten an answer for some days, which is why you might not have noticed most of them. This user was/is clearly a first-rate mathematician (in the actual meaning of this word, not just as a user on this site).

Comment: @quid: No, it does not. It says (a) that I happened to see only a few of his answers on the main site, and (b) that I thought those few good. That’s all. There is no implication that he answered only a few questions. Any misrepresentation that you read into is supplied by you. (And yes, I was aware of the magnitude of his numerical reputation; owing to our different mathematical interests, we just didn’t cross paths very often.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott many a reader of your comment would get away with a wrong idea about the contributions of this user, in this sense it misrepresents those contributions (while it might be factually correct it is misleading, as is the assertion that about a third of your answers that I happened to read in detail are somewhere between poor and false).

Comment: +1 for the question....I myself  quite often also find Najib Idrissi's tome quite aggresive...I don't understand why he behaves in this peculiar way...

Comment: I have to be honest, here. I think the question is/was a valid question; NormalHuman thrived in drama, and so this dramatic action surprises me not at all; probably is enjoying all the kudos placed here.. What amazes me is how many users forget/forgot/overlook(ed)/look(ed) the other way during NormalHuman's (the most recent formulation of his/her name) toxic deletion crusade. To be honest (as I promised) I won't miss his/her presence here.  So please, keep your eulogies to yourself, and don't try to make a hero out of a "normal human."

Comment: @Newb: He seems to be back: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/357151/6-white-male.

Answer (score 15):

End of July, to be precise, on or shortly before the 27th, I saw the about me of the user in question saying "delete me." This is part of the self-deletion process of SE for established accounts. The account was then deleted on July 27th.

User accounts of the same user on other sites were not deleted and continue to be active to this day. Indeed a math.se account linked to them  was recreated at some point. (It's still a 101 account, though. I do not link it on purpose. But whoever is so inclined should have no major trouble to find it.)

Thus, it seems overwhelmingly likely to me that the user *asked* for their *math* SE account to be deleted.

I observed on at least two occasions that the user was asked in chat about their reasons for this deletion. I did not see any reply, and thus assume they have no interest to discuss their motivation for this decision.

I hesitated to answer this question, as I am not sure about its suitability, but there it is the information I can offer as an attentive observer, in the hope of doing more good than harm.

Comment: ...Why can't SE seem to keep good people around?  Some (not all) moderators are always abusing their powers (e.g., punishing others, while approving of their own bad behaviors) or at least it comes off that way, and that's enough to make positive contributors flip out.  I know you're not a mod, just saying, though...I liked Normal Human a lot, too.

Comment: I agree with the final part of your comment.  :-) But please let's not turn this into a blame the moderators (or anyone, for that matter) thread.

Comment: Agreed, @quid :)

Comment: I asked in chat at some point, but he/she did not share. Regardless, I was and am very sad to see NormalHuman go. The site will certainly take a hit from that loss.

Comment: @User001 We all die of old age eventually XD